# Titanium Studio cannot find Android SDK from Android-Studio

Tags: android, titanium, android-sdk-tools

Im very aware this "forum" is full of this topics about Titanium, infact the topics here helped me the last years to set it up always. But not this time...

I got a new Laptop and now funny things are going on. I have Androidstudio installed that comes with an own sdk folder when installed. This is the same as the downloadable sdk to work with eclipse (at least i think so... has same folders and all).

Android Studio works fine with the SDK, be it Emulators or real Devices. Then i also had to install Titanium to work on an older project. Sadly i cannot get Titanium to work with any sdk now. I entered the right path to the SDK in Titanium of course and on the frontpage it shows me that Android SDK is correctly configured. But whenever i run a project i dont have any Android based options, only Preview in Web. So then i looked back into the Preferences and here it shows suddenly that theres no Android SDK in the specified folder. Even there is one in of course...

I switch back on Frontpage and still theres a green dot and the Android-Confi and it shows all good.

Now when i play around with the paths in the Preferences window weired things happen... Sometimes i can choose a Emulator Device that is already in the AVD-Manager but it disappears after i leave the menu....

I tried many things already, also download the standalone SDK from google, its the same. Also when i hit the Setup Button i get the options to download all the sdks, with 2 of them greyed-out and all others unchecked. But i have nearly every API Version completley installed, also for example 2.3.3 that is unchecked here. If i check and want to configure it downloads, installs and then nothing happens... When going back into the menu the same is checked/unchecked like before. But no error message when downloadeing.

What can it be?

[Bild1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxtia357r1kqioe/1.png)

[Bild2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9u4e2nveyiqsf2s/21.png)

Comment: Pic of the setup process that runs through but dont really installs something in real: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ncc94xek3ps4gh/Screenshot%202014-07-06%2021.04.36.png

Comment: Noone? Please help, i cannot get it to work still,.